# Angular Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use dual binding on md-select. Though I do have FormsModule injected as below

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
```

but for some reason it keeps complaining as below

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of
>   'md-select'.
>   1. If 'md-select' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

My template looks like:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedState"> 
    <md-option *ngFor="let mystate of states" [value]="mystate.short">
        {{ mystate.name }}
    </md-option> 
</md-select>
```

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: my bad, `<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedState">
                                <md-option *ngFor="let mystate of states" [value]="mystate.short">{{ mystate.name }}</md-option>
                            </md-select>`

Comment: did you see the below answer?

Comment: Do you have sub-modules? If so, did you import FormsModule there?

Comment: I didn't knew that we have to import FormsModule in child modules as well!!! Thanks, its solved :)